# Cookies are not set from Cross domain AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I am loading a javascript on my page http://vista.local/. The script sends a POST request to a webservice http://api.vista.local/sessions which sets the cookies is set in the response

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Origin, Content-Type, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://vista.local
Age:0
Cache-Control:public, max-age=1
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:36
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 23 Aug 2015 06:00:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:vista-session=c07c4d25-5c6e-47a3-9bbc-60f7d122075a;Domain=.vista.local;Path=/;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:vista-loggedin=true;Domain=.vista.local;Path=/;
Set-Cookie:vista-user-email=vista1839@yahoo.com;Domain=.vista.local;Path=/;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:vista-session-dummy=c07c4d25-5c6e-47a3-9bbc-60f7d122075a;Version=1
Set-Cookie:vista-secured-session=08239195-e95e-4f42-adeb-5d9c745ca853;Domain=.vista.local;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-UA:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
```

I tried different types of cookies.. HttpOnly, non-HttpOnly without domain, with domain. Nothing works.

My JS/JQuery code to request

```
function login(formdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url : api.sessions,
        method : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(formdata),
        dataType : 'text',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("yeeeii")
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(".error").html(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the withCredentials

```
...
method : "POST",
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
...
```

Comment: I took me more than a day to realise that `withCredentials` not only tells browser to attach cookies on request, but also tells it to set new cookies on response. It's the same with ajax options for `fetch` function where `credentials: 'include'` must be applied to make browser sending and setting cookies on request and response.