# Sending Cookie from Back in Go it's an api rest, to Front-end with React JS

Tags: reactjs, http, go, cookies, axios

Hi guys I have got a doubt I am learning golang and how to build and consume API'S. I've done almost all on the server-side (Golang), and In front-End (React.Js) I can make get/post Requests using Axios for Login, registration, Posts (The app will' be a Forum). The problem is when I want to protect some routes, when I'm trying to set the Cookie from the server-side, the front gets an empty Cookie, but instead, I can set up a cookie in front-End. Where should I create and manage the cookies and session?

I'll let some of the code.

Golang:

Handler's header:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
```

Cookie Go:

```
func SetCookie (w http.ResponseWriter) {
cookie := http.Cookie{
    Name: "LoginCookie",
    Value: "LoginCookieValue",
    Path: "/",
}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

}

The Cookie response in the browser from the server through AJAX Request(Axios) from the front end:

```
Cookie: {Name: "", Value: "", Path: "", Domain: "", Expires: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", …}
```

But instead Using React I can create a cookie and see in the browser:

```
      setCookie() {
    const cookieName = 'LoginCookie'
    const cookieVal = uuidv4()
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    cookies.set(cookieName, cookieVal , { path: '/' });
    console.log(cookies.get(cookieName));
  }
```

What I should do? Thanks anyway.

EDIT: Here I let the complete Axios request as a member suggest:

```
   async submit (event) {

var userLogin = {
  email: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password
}

let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

   event.preventDefault();

   await axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/users/sign-in/`, userLogin, axiosConfig,
     {withCredentials: true})
   .then(response => {
       console.log(response)
       console.log(response.data)
       console.log(response.data.status)
       console.log(response.data.cookie)
       if (response.data.status === 200) {
         this.setCookie()
       }
       this.clearFieldLogin()
       
   }).catch(err => console.log(err))

  }

  clearFieldLogin(){
    document.getElementById("formLogin").reset()
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookies are not set from Cross domain AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750507/cookies-are-not-set-from-cross-domain-ajax-request)

Comment: No, Peter, I saw that post before post my issue.

Comment: You should use `credentials: 'include'` option for [`fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies)

Comment: I am working with Axios, Should i work with fetch? where I've to put credentials: 'include'

Comment: oh, my bad I was thinking you're using fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set cookie on the backend and read it in react, the `{ withCredentials: true }` options should be in the axiosConfig object:

```
axiosConfig["withCredentials"] = true
await axios.post(
    `http://localhost:2000/users/sign-in/`,
     userLogin, 
     axiosConfig,
 )
```

Your wrong code:

```
await axios.post(
   `http://localhost:2000/users/sign-in/`,
    userLogin, 
    axiosConfig,
    {withCredentials: true}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I should to suggest to check your code of AJAX request.
I think you have a mistake in configuration of sending request to server-side.

Do you have `withCredentials: true` option?

Secondly, you could try to set `Expires` to your server-side Cookie object.

```
expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "username", Value: "astaxie", Expires: expiration}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

Comment: There is the full AJAX request now, you can check it. About expiration time I'll be set, but first I need to make it works. I've set withCredential: true. Thanks.